# Problemas .htacess

Tags: htaccess, joomla

Fiz um site em Joomla e estamos implantando no servidor do cliente (UOL HOST)
porém deparei com um problema.

O site antigo estava dentro da pasta do ftp: dominio.com.br/web

Colocamos os arquivos em outra pasta e subimos o novo conteúdo para essa pasta. Ao acessar tudo estava ok, porém com um problema: Na URL do site começou a mostrar esses diretórios do ftp no link:

```
www.dominio.com.br/var/www/dominio.com.br/web
```

No Joomla temos a opção de habilitar o mod_rewrite do servidor para que a url fique amigável. Portanto essa URL seria oculta.

Acontece que dentro do servidor isso não aconteceu.

Dentro da pasta do site, enviamos um arquivo .htaccess que utilizamos em outros clientes e apenas alteramos a url, porém nada aconteceu também.

Se no Joomla eu desabilito a opção de mod_rewrite, todo esse diretório de pastas some, porém fica aquele famoso "index.php" substituindo no lugar e as outras urls ficam "sujas", portanto não posso deixar assim.

Queríamos manter o esquema de URL amigável, porém com esse link do ftp oculto na URL.

Já tentei jogar o site na pasta raíz (fora desse dominio.com.br/web) e fica a mesma coisa, ele adiciona o tal do "var/www/" na URL.

Também tentei entrar no UOL Host para ver se havia como desabilitar ou mudar essa pasta raíz do FTP, porém sem sucesso.

Alguém tem ideia do que possa ser?

Não tenho muito conhecimento de configuração de servidores, porém segui o padrão de outros que fizemos e não tive esse problema. Por ser UOL Host e diferente dos outros que hospedamos, creio que seja algo na hospedagem.

Apenas para conhecimento, estou colocando abaixo como está meu .htaccess

```
##
# @package    Joomla
# @copyright  Copyright (C) 2005 - 2015 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license    GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that disallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## No directory listings
IndexIgnore *

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymlinks
Options -Indexes

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver o problema. Para pessoas que futuramente tiver esse problema com o UOL Host, basta pegar o arquivo .htaccess padrão do Joomla e tirar o "#" que comenta a linha "RewriteBase /".

Caso o site esteja instalado em uma subpasta, ficaria assim:

"RewriteBase /diretorio-do-site"

Abraço

Comment: Obrigado!
Resolveu aqui tambem!

Comment: Obrigado!!!! Resolveu aqui também!!!